Is it appropriate to use PCA scores as response variables in a GLMM to compare two experimental conditions?
I conducted a within-subject experiment with 40 participants, where each participant was exposed to two conditions. They completed a survey with nine 5-point Likert scale questions after each condition. Given the intercorrelation of the Likert scale responses, I performed a Principal Component Analysis (PCA), which resulted in two principal components explaining over 70% of the variance.
I plan to use these principal component scores as the response variables in a GLMM to compare the two conditions, with condition and survey phase (same survey repeated for each condition twice, before and after the experiment) as fixed effects, and participant as a random effect.
formula:

PC1 (and PC2) ~ Condition * Phase + (1|Participant)

Is this approach statistically sound, and are there any potential pitfalls I should be aware of?
Thank you for your insights!

Do you care what the principal components mean? That is, are the constructs behind PC1 and PC2 well-defined and understood? PCA is a completely atheoretical data reduction technique. That's great if you don't care about what the principal components represent. But since they are the outcomes in your model, I think you must care about them somewhat.
If so, you may want to use factor analysis instead. It allows you to perform both exploratory analysis to help you understand the dimensionality of the measure (similar to PCA). It also allows for the mapping of particular items onto latent variables (factors) in a theoretically-sound way.
See the following web resources:
https://bookdown.org/sz_psyc490/r4psychometics/factor-analysis.html
https://quantdev.ssri.psu.edu/tutorials/intro-basic-exploratory-factor-analysis
https://quantdev.ssri.psu.edu/tutorials/intro-basic-confirmatory-factor-analysis

Thank you for your answer. The first thing I want to do is to interpret which variables (answers to survey questions) most correlate with the new components. So that I will understand what each of those dimension might be representing (User Experience, Learning, etc). Then I wanted to fit a model on those scores. However, by what you mention it seems more reasonable to start with FA and use the scores resulted from FA instead to fit my models. If I understood correctly, the FA is more appropriate for my case. Am I right?
